# Tool For FSM Minimization

Tags: optimization

Can anyone suggest me a good (possibly open-source) tool able to take a finite state automaton (either deterministic or nondeterministic) and to calculate the corresponding optimal automaton?

It would be great if the tool was able to convert a nondeterministic automaton to a deterministic one.

Comment: I know some of the terms you're using and not others.  Can you provide more background by defining the terms 'finished state automaton' (and how it can be deterministic or non-deterministic) and an optimal automaton?  I've heard of finite state machines but I don't know if a 'finished state automaton' is the same or similar or none of the above.

Comment: @AngryEE all of those are standard terms - wikipedia is your friend -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: After the edit, yes they're all standard terms.  Before he didn't call it a finite state machine (which I'm familiar with).  I've looked like an idiot more times than I can count by assuming what people meant when it was something else.  Now I guess I've found a new way to look like an idiot ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are tools... But they are language specific.

http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/fpga/fsm_optimization/

http://members.fortunecity.com/boroday/Automatatools.html

http://poppy.snu.ac.kr/~kchoi/class/lc_intro/fsm_opt.pdf
(last page)

http://www.fizzim.com/

Anyways, you should be a bit more clear on what exactly you want to do. There are tools and google is your friend.

Comment: Second and third links are broken.